# Tor unable to connect to onion sites, able to connect to clearnet sites

Tags: configuration, connection

I've been using tor for a while now with no issue. However a couple days ago I stopped being able to connect to tor sites. When I try to connect to a clearnet site on tor, it works perfectly fine. But when I try to connect to an onion site, I get the following error message. I've tried connecting on multiple different devices, different os's, and different networks, but nothing works.

"The connection has timed out
The operation timed out when attempting to contact "onionsite.onion."
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy.
Try again in a few moments.If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the web."

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: attach a log, please! especially a debug one with credentials stripped off. It's impossible to diagnose the situation without it